# Turn off Sim 2 in Android automatically

Tags: android, sh

I have 2 sim cards in my OnePlus 3, sim 1 is my personal one and sim 2 is a work number. I want to turn off sim 2 outside of work hours automatically so I don't forget, to save power and not be disturbed. I have rooted my phone and tried this solution: https://forum.xda-developers.com/canvas-a1/help/how-to-turnoff-sim2-dual-sim-t3202837

All `setprop persist.radio.multisim.config` seems to do is disable the menu option for sim 2. I can still call it, so it isn't off. I would ideally like a .sh script I can run from tasker (I have root access).